# Disable html escaping in Jackson serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

During json serialization, jackson is converting `&` to `&amp;`. How do I disable this automatic conversion?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I don't know which setting controls this. Is there such a setting in jackson?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: I had a look at it, by default jackson is not escaping anything, so you would need to give a full example.